# How to fix refreshing with asp net (using model for data)

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am currently developing a Site using Asp net for ordering food. I am pretty much finished but I am having a big problem.
After I click the (Browser)Back Button I am gettig an Error. Something like "the local copy of the website is not the latest version any more".
After refreshing there is no error anymore and the site shows like it should so.

Is there any solution for me so that the user doesnt has to refresh?

Comment: You should disable the clicking of the back button to avoid re-submissions

Comment: I can't disable the Browser-Back-Button

Comment: Sorry... I meant intercept. You can use the window beforeunload event and cancel it.

Comment: @Wheels73 can you explain this a bit more detailed for me please

Comment: Well i know you can't "Stop" the back button from being pressed, but you can add some client script to capture them leaving the page and warn them not to do so if that helps?

Comment: @Wheels73 okey now i understand what you mean thanks :) now i have to google how to do it

Comment: @L.Kaisi - no..  I can tell you :)   In your pages script block.. add  window.onbeforeunload = function () {
        return "Are you sure you want to leave this page?";
    }   I use Chrome, it doesn't pop up that exact message but gives a leave / cancel option.

Comment: What's the exact error? Intercepting the back button to disable it is bad design.

Comment: @Wheels73 is it possible to dissable this function ? For example if i click an button ?

Comment: @SteveJ translated form German: "The local copy of the website is out of date. The site requires you to download it again."

Comment: Is that when you click back after POSTing a form?

Comment: @SteveJ when clicking the browser back button

Comment: Yes, but what action has the user done before that? It sounds like everything is working as expected. If a form POSTs data to a web server then it is assumed that the state of the system is being changed. The browser is supposed to warn the user in this situation that the data is out of date.

Comment: @SteveJ yes i am posting data to a server. So there is no way to prevent this from happening? Is this what you are saying

Comment: The usual flow would be to have an anchor link on the page after the POST to take the user back which would perform a GET request and not cause the issue.

Comment: @SteveJ can you show me how to do this ?

Comment: Simply have a link such as this `<a href="http://url-of-previous-page">Continue</a>` and maybe style it up to look like a button.

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution[may be this is not perfect one], Reload your page on click of browser back button

By Javascript

```
 window.addEventListener("pageshow", function (event) {
        var historyTraversal = event.persisted || (typeof window.performance != "undefined" && window.performance.navigation.type === 2);
        if (historyTraversal) {
            window.location.reload();
        }
    });
```